# What are the minimal conditions for the exactness of a 1-form on an open connected subset?

Tags: real-analysis

When considering a continuous $\omega\in\Lambda^1(U)$, where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is some open connected subset, $d\omega=0$ is insufficient to guarantee exactness since Poincare's Lemma holds for contractible manifolds, and $U$ may not be one.

(Note in below discussion I assume all paths/loops are $\mathcal{C}^1$ singular 1-cells) If *every* loop $\gamma$ in $U$ satisfies $\int_\gamma\omega=0$, then we know that for any two points $\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}\in U$ any two paths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2\in U$ from $\textbf{a}$ to $\textbf{b}$ can be concatenated such that $\gamma_1-\gamma_2$ forms a loop so we have path independence for *every path* in $U$ since $\int_{\gamma_1-\gamma_2}\omega =0$.

Complete path independence in $U$ results in exactness since it ensures that $\forall\textbf{a},\textbf{x}\in U$, $f(\textbf{x})=\int_{[\textbf{a},\textbf{x}]}\omega$ is well-defined, which we can use to show $d f=\omega$ in an open neighborhood of every $\textbf{x}$ by looking at the difference of $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(\textbf{x}+h{\boldsymbol\delta}_i)-f(\textbf{x})$ for $1\le i \le n$.

However, [this question's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612837/how-to-compute-the-de-rham-cohomology-of-the-punctured-plane-just-by-calculus) by @Seub (see "Lemma 3") seems to imply a sufficient condition for exactness is path independence solely about the 2 paths of the oriented cell $\Delta(\textbf{a},\textbf{x})$ (in $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$). How is this the case? It make sense, looking at how the proof for exactness works given that $\omega$ is completely path independent, but the first statement in that proof ($f$ is well-defined) is now in question.

If, as @Seub mentions, we restrict all possible paths $[\textbf{a},\textbf{x}]$ to just ones on $\partial \Delta(\textbf{a},\textbf{x})$, then I agree $f$ is well defined, and $df=\omega$ on the boundary of $\Delta(\textbf{a},\textbf{x})$. Why can we then "extend" its exactness to an open interval around $\textbf{b}$? Does it have something to do with continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, well-definedness isn't in question. As you yourself say in the last paragraph, you define $f$ by integrating on paths that are (locally) parallel to the coordinate axes. You end up with a smooth function whose *partial derivatives* are computed by taking exactly such paths, and hence you've verified that $df=\omega$. Your sentence "$df=\omega$ on the boundary of $\Delta(\mathbf a,\mathbf x)$" is not right; this equality holds everywhere on our domain, as you verify that it holds at every $\mathbf a\in U$.

Comment: I see. Could you please clarify what the minimal condition for exactness is then? It seems that all that's needed is that for every $\textbf{a},\textbf{x}$, that there really only need to be $n$ paths with equivalent integrals, one for each dimension, where the paths don't even need to trace out $\partial\Delta$ fully, but just near $\textbf{x}$.

Comment: Well, the problem is still a global one. If your region is not simply connected, there will be paths consisting of line segments parallel to the axes that give different integrals. There's no way to remove global topological considerations.

Comment: Yes - I mean they still need to be connected, but the paths from $\textbf{a}$ to $\textbf{x}$ are only parallel to the axes in some open set about $\textbf{x}$. If $n$ such paths exist and have the same integrals, one for each dimension, then do we have exactness?

Comment: Think about $\Bbb R^2 - \{(0,0)\}$. You still need to know that if you take a path $C$ (made out of line segments parallel to the axes or not) that goes around the origin, then $\int_C\omega=0$.