# Second cohomology group of twice-punctured plane

Tags: homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I am looking for pure calculus solution for computing the second cohomology class $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2-\{p , q\}, \mathbb{R})$ i.e. plane with two points removed.

I know that every closed $2$-form is exact for $\mathbb{R}^2-\{p , q\}$, but I cannot find the explicit $1$-form for every $2$-form that under the exterior derivative produces the $2$-form. I want to "integrate" the  $2$-form and get the $1$-form by "d" operator. Note you have to somehow integrate "around" the points.

This is a problem from page 19 of Bott and Tu. I am trying to read the book on my own which would not be brought up in May if this was a Spring course.

Comment: What does "pure calculus type of solution" mean? Do you want the computation of the De Rham complex? What kind of cohomology do you know how to calculate? This is unclear without added details.

Comment: Every closed 2-form is exact for R2−{p,q}, I cannot find the explicit 1-form for every 2-form that under the exterior derivative produces the 2-form. I want to "integrate" the 2-form and get the 1-form by "d" operator. Note you have to somehow integrate "around" the points.

Comment: In other words, you want to explicitly compute a generating set for $H^2$ DeRham. Is this what you're thinking of?

Comment: For one point removed, you can integrate the 2-form in polar coordinates from the circle of radius 1 to that point along rays( toward) the point removed, I think; that gives you the 1-form in the polar coordinates. How about 2 points removed? How do we integrate the 2-form. I am fine with using polar coordinates if need be.

Comment: @alireza: please include an @ before a name to make sure the recipient gets the message. Also, what 2-form are you referring to, which you integrate?

Comment: @alireza: Maybe you can use the explicit isomorphism between DeRham cohomology and singular cohomology once you know the actual top cohomology

Comment: @user99680   Because $H^2(R^2-\{p,q\})$ is trivial, we know every closed two form here must be exact. It must be possible to obtain every closed two form by exterior derivative then from a one form. right? So I would like to compute the one form that maps to that closed form.

Comment: @PVAL Every closed 2-form is exact for R2−{p,q}, I cannot find the explicit 1-form for every 2-form that under the exterior derivative produces the 2-form. I want to "integrate" the 2-form and get the 1-form by "d" operator. Note you have to somehow integrate "around" the points.

Comment: @alireza: Sorry, I meant to say we want a generating set for $H^1$ , not for $H^2$. Yes, once you have a generating set for $H^1$ ,  I think this would give you the top forms. I think using DeRham's theorem will allow you to obtain these 1-forms explicitly. I will continue working; do you have an e-mail , in case they close this question? I will get back to you if I get something.

Comment: @user99680   my gmail is alireza1976haha

Comment: @alireza: hopefully you will laugh last ( re the haha ) with an answer : ).

Answer (score 4):

$H$ below denotes de Rham cohomology, so this is a pure calculus proof. I assume only that you know that $H^2(\mathbf R^2)=0$, which itself follows from $H^1(\mathbf R)=0$ by the Künneth decomposition.

First, it suffices to calculate $H^2(\mathbf R^2-{p})$, because $$(\mathbf R^2-{p}) \cap (\mathbf R^2-{q}) = \mathbf R^2-\{p,q\}$$ and
$$(\mathbf R^2-{p}) \cup (\mathbf R^2-{q}) = \mathbf R^2;$$
since $H^2(\mathbf R^2) = 0,$ the Mayer-Vietoris sequence gives an isomorphism 
$$H^2(\mathbf R^2-\{p,q\}) = H^2(\mathbf R^2-{p}) \oplus H^2(\mathbf R^2-{q}).$$

Now, remark that $$\mathbf R^2-{0} = (\mathbf R^2-(X)) \cup (\mathbf R^2-(Y))$$
where $(X),(Y)$ are the axes. Remark also that

$$(\mathbf R^2-(X)) \cap (\mathbf R^2-(Y)) = \mathbf R^2-(X)\cup (Y)$$

and this last open set is diffeomorphic to the disjoint union of $4$ copies of $\mathbf R^2$, hence its $H^2$ vanishes. Thus, Mayer-Vietoris again identifies $H^2(\mathbf R^2-0)$ with 
$$H^2(\mathbf R^2-(X))\oplus H^2(\mathbf R^2-(Y))$$
But again, each of $\mathbf R^2-(X)$ and $\mathbf R^2-(Y)$ is diffeomorphic to 2 copies of $\mathbf R^2$, so the $H^2$ vanishes. Therefore $H^2(\mathbf R^2-p)$ vanishes, and so does $H^2(\mathbf R^2-\{p,q\})$.

Comment: This implies the every closed 2-form is exact obviously then, I cannot find the explicit 1-form for every 2-form that under the exterior derivative produces the 2-form.  @Bruno Joyal

Comment: Dear @alireza If you follow the steps in my proof, and you understand how the maps in Mayer-Vietoris are constructed, you can make a primitive explicit.

Comment: The exercise is given before introduction of Mayer-Vietoris sequences so I think the book wants you to solve it without it. But even so, I cannot see it. Please elaborate how to compute the one form that gives the two forms here.

Comment: @alireza Are you reading Bott & Tu? I don't think that exercise is meant to be solvable without any tools at all. In fact, it's probably meant to illustrate that it is difficult to calculate cohomology groups without any tools. As for how to find a primitive, I'll leave it up to you to figure it out.

Comment: yes. I can solve it without any use of subsequent development for H1 but not H2. It should be doable, but thanks for trying anyway @  Bruno Joyal

Comment: @alireza You are welcome. It is certainly doable. As I said, working backwards from my answer will give you a primitive. Also, let me point out that in the formulation of your question, you ask about "the" $1$-form whose derivative is the given $2$-form. This is misleading: there is more than one such $1$-form.

Comment: yes obviously   @Bruno Joyal

Comment: @Gil Bor   I think I got it via partition of unity( I know how to do it with one hole so ):   d w_1= \roh_u w and d w_2=\roh_v w then d(w_1+w+2)= (\roh_u + \roh_v) w= w     each operating on their own side and not worrying about the other hole since the \roh's suppress the function there right? :)

Comment: These 3 answers are precisely what I was looking for: an answer by Mayer-Vietoris, an answer by homotopy with figure 8 space aka a wedge of 2 circles and an answer using only Chapter 1 definitions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that constructions from the Mayer-Vietoris sequence or Kuenneth formulas or other devices would be in the spirit of the first portion of Bott and Tu.  If you, like me, worry about these things, then remember that if we're going to do freshman calculus---and we need to---it is perfectly legitimate to choose our coordinates.  We can always translate, rotate, and scale coordinates to place our points where we want them.  It is very nice, then to have $P:(x=-1, y=1)$ and $Q:(x=1,y=-1)$, and, as I said, this can be done passively just by choosing our coordinates to our own liking.  We know that all the 2-forms are closed because we are at the highest grade for this space.  An ordinary 2-form might be $g(x,y) dx \wedge dy$, perhaps.  So, why can't we just do freshman calculus and consider for our own pleasure $\omega= -(\frac{1}{2})(\int_0^y g(x, \eta) d\eta) dx + (\frac{1}{2})(\int_0^x g(\xi, y)d\xi)dy$?  It is a very nice 1-form, I think, and it is one of very many that will have $d$ leading us where we want to go.  We really only need a sort of slightly disguised version of the fundamental theorem for a single variable, and all is well.  So, all the 2-forms are exact, and the cohomology vanishes.  Only the words are more confusing than freshman year, nothing more. I think this is sort of the spirit of Bott for the 2-grade.

Comment: These 3 answers are precisely what I was looking for: an answer by Mayer-Vietoris, an answer by homotopy with figure 8 space aka a wedge of 2 circles and an answer using only Chapter 1 definitions. Thanks!

Comment: $g$ may diverge at $P$ or $Q$, thus the integrals in your definition of $\omega$ may not be defined. For example, take $P=(-1,0),\ Q=(1,0)$, and the 2-form ${\left(x-1\right)}^{-1} dx \wedge dy$.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to write down an answer that didn't use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence explicitly, although it is certainly just this underneath. I however found it useful to try to get some deeper insight on the inner workings of the theorem. The general lesson that learnt from this, which is of course a simple corollary of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, is that if a $k$-form $\omega$ can be written as an exact form $\text{d}\alpha$ on $U$ and $\text{d}\beta$ on $V$, and $U\cap V$ is such that every closed $(k-1)$-form is exact, then $\omega$ can in fact be written as an exact form on $U\cup V$.

The procedure in order to do this is the following. First, note that the difference between the two expression of $\omega$ on $U\cap V$ is closed, since $\text{d}(\alpha-\beta)=\omega-\omega=0$. The assumption on $U\cap V$ implies then that this difference is exact. In other words, there is a $(k-2)$-form $\gamma$ such that $\alpha=\beta+\text{d}\gamma$ on the intersection. Of course, we would like this to extend to all of $U\cup V$. In order to do so, we choose a partition of unity $\{\rho_U,\rho_V\}$ subordinate to $\{U,V\}$. We can then define the $(k-2)$-forms $\rho_U\gamma$ on $V$ and $\rho_V\gamma$ on $U$. We can then slightly modify our $(k-1)$-forms to $\alpha'=\alpha-\text{d}(\rho_V\gamma)$ and $\beta'=\beta+\text{d}(\rho_U\gamma)$. They are still representations of $\omega$ on their respective domains since they differ from the original ones by closed forms but now have a very nice property: they agree on the intersection
$$\alpha'-\beta'=\alpha-\beta-\text{d}((\rho_V+\rho_U)\gamma)=\alpha-\beta-\text{d}\gamma=\alpha-\alpha=0.$$
They can thus be extended to a single $(k-1)$-form $\mu$. Moreover $\omega=\text{d}\mu$.

The intuition here is clear. The function $\rho_V$ vanishes far away from $V$, such that $\alpha'$ coincides with $\alpha$ there. However, as we are about to leave $U$ and enter $V$ it becomes $1$, such that $\alpha'=\beta$ there. In other words, $\alpha'$ smoothly interpolates between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Moreover, it does so in a very special way which is where the hypothesis enters. Note that we could've still done this smoothing directly on the difference of our two forms $\rho_V\text{d}\gamma$. However, unlike $\text{d}\gamma$, this is not closed.

One thus only need to consider a cover of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p,q\}$ by two half-spaces, each surrounding only one of the removed points and intersecting on a strip, which would satisfy the conditions above $H^1(U\cap V)=0$. The proof that any 2-form is exact on each of these opens can be found in Ted Shiffrin's answer in [how to compute the de Rham cohomology of the punctured plane just by Calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612837/how-to-compute-the-de-rham-cohomology-of-the-punctured-plane-just-by-calculus). Alternatively, one can further decompose each of these opens following Bruno Joyal's excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

The plane with two points removed retracts to a wedge of circles. Start at $p$ and gradually unfold , i.e., make the hole about $p$ larger. Do the same with $q$ simultaneously. Maybe doing this in a square first will help. Then, by homotopy invariance, the homology of  $\mathbb R^2 -$ {$p,q$} is that of a wedge of two circles. For the top homology alone, you just need to decide if $\mathbb R^2 -$ $p,q$ is orientable or not.

If you prefer something more computational, you may want to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, and it would help if you accept that the plane minus a point, equivalently, the plane minus a disk retracts to $S^1$, and you know the (co)homology of $\mathbb R^2$. I can only think of one decomposition for  using Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: Every closed 2-form is exact for R2−{p,q}, I cannot find the explicit 1-form for every 2-form that under the exterior derivative produces the 2-form. I want to "integrate" the 2 form and get the 1-form by "d" operator. Note you have to somehow integrate "around" the points. Can it be done without using Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Comment: Well, you can maybe use the fact that all homology theories are isomorphic. Then if you use Mayer-Vietoris, you know the DeRham cohomology, i.e., the cohomology in terms of differential forms, and then find generating forms using the actual maps in the MV sequence. Or, by homotopy invariance, you can find the forms in the wedge of 2 circles. I cannot think of any other method.

Comment: "you can find the forms in the wedge of 2 circles." yes something like that. please elaborate. I think we need to integrate the 2-form "around" the points somehow.

Comment: O.K, let me give it a try; it has been a while.

Comment: These 3 answers are precisely what I was looking for: an answer by Mayer-Vietoris, an answer by homotopy with figure 8 space aka a wedge of 2 circles and an answer using only Chapter 1 definitions. Thanks!