# integral over rectangle to compute de Rham cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I am trying to reconstruct Seub's proof to calculate the first de Rham cohomology of the punctered plane :
[how to compute the de Rham cohomology of the punctured plane just by Calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612837/how-to-compute-the-de-rham-cohomology-of-the-punctured-plane-just-by-calculus)
In particular, when $M = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$:
"Fix permanently some point $m_0 \in M$, whichever you like best. For any $m\in M$, consider a rectangle $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose boundary contains $m_0$ and $m$ but avoids the origin."
As I understand it, 0 must be in the interior of the rectangle $R$. But I have a hard time to understand this, for example say that $m_0=(1,1)$ and $m=(2,2)$, then there is no such rectangle. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Why must "$0$ be in the interior of the rectangle"?

Comment: It doesn't have to- that was my mistake, as Eric pointed out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding.  It is not necessary that $0$ is in the interior of the rectangle.  The point is that we want to find an antiderivative of $\alpha$ by taking a path integral (this is basically a two-dimensional form of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which says that for nice functions on $\mathbb{R}$ you can find an antiderivative by integrating).  However, in order to get a well-defined function by integrating and verify that its derivative really is $\alpha$, we need the integral to be independent of the path we choose.  Now if you take two paths along a rectangle, those paths will automatically give the same integral if $0$ is not in the interior of the rectangle, so actually we would *prefer* if $0$ were *not* in the interior.  But if $0$ is in the interior, the integrals will differ by $\lambda(\alpha)$, and so since we are assuming $\lambda(\alpha)=0$, we're actually still OK.  So in this context we don't care whether $0$ is in the interior of our rectangles.